# How do I output a set used as key for a map?

Tags: c++

I get this error when I compile this code:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::set;
    using std::map;

    set<int> s;
    s.insert(4);
    s.insert(3);

    map<set<int>, int> myMap;

    myMap.insert(make_pair(s, 8));

    for (map<set<int>, int>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end();
            it++) {

        std::cout << it->first << "->" << it->second << std::endl; // HERE
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is from the line marked `//HERE`:

> error: cannot bind `std::ostream` {aka `std::basic_ostream<char>`} lvalue to `std::basic_ostream<char>&&`

Comment: The key type for you map is a set!? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: it should be an array,vector or set

Comment: `it->first` is a `std::set<int>`, and there's no stream insertion operator for that. I have no solution as I have no idea what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: so what I can do?

Comment: I have some integer in a set or it can be in array or vector and I want to map some of them to zero and some of them to 1

Comment: thats very weird to have a set as a key of a map. What do you expect the operations to be? What is op= for a set of int,  and op<?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a stream operator for the key type.

I personally dislike creating the overload in the `std` namespace, so I create a "manipulator" wrapper:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b782340c5747434f)</kbd>**

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
struct io {
    io(T const& t) : t(t) {}
  private:
    T const& t;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, io const& o) {
        os << "{ ";
        using namespace std;
        copy(begin(o.t), end(o.t), ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(os, " "));
        return os << "}";
    }
};

int main() {  
    using namespace std;
    auto myMap = map<set<int>, int> { { { { 4, 3 }, 8 } } };

    for (auto& [k,v] : myMap)
        std::cout << io{k} << " -> " << v << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
{ 3 4 } -> 8
```

- A version just using c++11: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfb571f3e43bda18
- A version just using c++03: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f28f8f90c386b50 (man that was tedious)

Comment: Beyond disliking it, it’s [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) to do so!

Comment: its very complex for me

Comment: It's c++, I'm afraid it will not get less complex.

Comment: Here's something that might help you understand the code: [in imperative fashion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d812dece2ea19c1). It results in less generic and less idiomatic C++. Notably, now it will not work for `set<int>` and `vector<int>` at the same time, but perhaps you like it better?