# Template specialization (boost::lexical_cast)

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-specialization

I want to extend the `lexical_cast` method for `vector<uint>` types, but it's not working. 
I tried the following code:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace boost
{
    template <>
    inline string lexical_cast <string>(vector<uint> source)
    {
        string tmp;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < source.size(); ++i)
            if (i < source.size() - 1)
                tmp += boost::lexical_cast<string>(source[i]) + "|";
            else
                tmp += boost::lexical_cast<string>(source[i]);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

I got following error:

> error: template-id ‘lexical_cast’ for ‘std::string
>   boost::lexical_cast(std::vector)’ does not match any
>   template declaration

Comment: You cannot change the prototype of the function template you're specializing, [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/lexical_cast.hpp) takes its argument by `const&`. Your code will compile if you change the parameter type to `vector<uint> const&`. But use one of the alternate methods described in the answer below, it's usually a bad idea to specialize function templates, see http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 3):

Lexical cast can be extended by overloading `operator<<`.

Problem is that `std::vector` nor `uint` are your types: they're builtin or standard library. This makes it not-okay for you to overload or specialize inside the namespace.

Real solution:

### Use a strong User-Defined Type

C++ is favors strong typing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

struct Source {
    std::vector<uint> _data;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Source const& s) {
        bool first = true;
        for(auto i : s._data) {
            if (!first) os << "|";
            first = false;
            os << i;
        }
        return os;
    }
};
```

> **BONUS** `lexical_cast` now magically works!

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88f13d7ef0123c92)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // for std::quoted

int main() {
    Source s { {1,2,3,4,5} };
    std::cout << "Source is " << s << "\n";

    std::string text = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(s);

    std::cout << "Length of " << std::quoted(text) << " is " << text.length() << "\n";

}
```

Prints

```
Source is 1|2|3|4|5
Length of "1|2|3|4|5" is 9
```

### Adapt for IO

Use a custom IO Manipulator like e.g. [How do I output a set used as key for a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941899/how-do-i-output-a-set-used-as-key-for-a-map/46942216#46942216)

```
#include <ostream>

template <typename Container>
struct pipe_manip {
    Container const& _data;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, pipe_manip const& manip) {
        bool first = true;
        for(auto& i : manip._data) {
            if (!first) os << "|";
            first = false;
            os << i;
        }
        return os;
    }
};

template <typename Container>
pipe_manip<Container> as_pipe(Container const& c) { return {c}; }
```

These also work with Boost Lexicalcast:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d831ac5ac0443b66)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<uint> s { {1,2,3,4,5} };
    std::cout << "Source is " << as_pipe(s) << "\n";

    std::string text = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(as_pipe(std::set<std::string>{"foo", "bar", "qux"}));
    std::cout << "Other containers work too: " << text << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Source is 1|2|3|4|5
Other containers work too: bar|foo|qux
```

Comment: Adding the manipulator approach too, [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d831ac5ac0443b66)